# Does there exist a holomorphic map s.t. $f({1\over 2})={3 \over 4}$ and $f'({1\over 2})={2\over 3}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $\mathbb D=\{ z\in \mathbb C||z|<1\}$.Does there exist a holomorphic function $f:\mathbb D \to \mathbb D$ such that $f({1\over 2})={3\over 4}$ and $f'({1\over 2})={2\over 3}?$

We know that if  $f$ be holomorphic then $\displaystyle f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_n(z-{1\over 2})^n$ ,where  $c_n={f^{(n)}({1\over 2})\over{n!}}$. From here we can find $c_0={3\over 4}$ and $c_1={2\over 3}.$ Using these how can we conclude whether such $f$ exists or not?

Please someone help..

Thank you..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f:\mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{D}$ is holomorphic, then it follows from the [Schwarz-Pick theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma#Schwarz.E2.80.93Pick_theorem) that
$$ \frac{|f^{\prime}(z)|}{1-|f(z)|^2}\leq \frac{1}{1-|z|^2} $$
Taking $z=\frac{1}{2},f(z)=\frac{3}{4}$, and $f^{\prime}(z)=\frac{2}{3}$, this becomes
$$ \frac{\frac{2}{3}}{1-\frac{9}{16}}\leq \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{4}}$$
or
$$ \frac{2}{3}\leq \frac{7}{12}$$
which is absurd. Hence no such $f$ exists.